# Batch increment part of variable name

Tags: variables, batch-file

How can I increment part of a variable name?

EG. i want to increment

filename holds something like  `mmddyyyy-prev01-Database.mdb`
and I'm trying to rename it to `mmddyyyy-prev02-Database.mdb`
With the code

```
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /a nextFileName=!fileName:~0,13!!fileName:~13!+1
```

and I get the error 
`Missing operator.`

I am using this to make a batch sub that will recursively rename the `prevXX` items so that the newest one is always `prev01`. I'm also doing regular `setlocal` in my method to keep the variables from getting mixed up between the deeper calls

Comment: I'm going with the one that just moves them on its own, but for any future people who encounter this situation and want to build your own solution, either of the other answers include great batch functions that return the newfilename in a variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going the hard way:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL disableDelayedExpansion
FOR /f "delims=" %%x IN ('DIR /b /a-d /o-n *-prev*-Database.mdb') DO (
    FOR /f "tokens=1-3*delims=v-" %%a IN ("%%~x") DO (
        FOR /f "tokens=*delims=0" %%e IN ("0%%c") DO (
            FOR /f %%f IN ('SET /a %%e+1') DO (
                IF %%f LEQ 9 (
                    ECHO REN "%%~x" "%%~a-%%~bv0%%~f-%%~d"
                ) ELSE (
                    ECHO REN "%%~x" "%%~a-%%~bv%%~f-%%~d"
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Just remove the `ECHO`s to make it working.

Comment: I was gonna work on building my own function to do it, but this just almost already does it. it does move ALL of the prevs down, not just the ones for the current day. I added `set currDate=%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%%date:~10,4%` and changed `DIR /b /a-d /o-n *-prev*-Database.mdb` to `DIR /b /a-d /o-n %currdate%*-prev*-INX0400.mdb` and it works great!

Answer (score 2):

`SET /A` won't allow you do this.

You'll have to break up into two lines, like this:

```
SET BaseFileName=!FileName:~0,13!
SET /A Counter=!FileName:~13!+1
```

Then, put the pieces back together:

```
SET NextFileName=%BaseFileName%%Counter%-Database.mdb
```

NOTE: This will not handle your leading `0`...you'll have to write more code for that.

Comment: So, I'd have to keep the base filename and then do the arithmetic on just the number portion and recombine. Makes sense

Answer (score 2):

```
...
set filename=mmddyyyy-prev01-Database.mdb
call :nextname
ren %filename% %newname%
...


:nextname
set /a newname=1%filename:~13,2%+1
set newname=%filename:~0,13%%newname:~-2%%filename:~15%
goto :eof
```

Whether you'd use `ren %filename% %newname%` or `ren !filename! !newname!` is a matter of context. You've posted insufficient code to be certain. If, as I suspect, you are executing the `ren` in a loop, then you would need the `!var!` form and delayedexpansion (with which you appear familiar.) Within the subroutine `:nextname`, the `%var%` form should be used.

**but** remember that you need to rename your existing files in reverse-alphabetical order, so

```
mmddyyyy-prev03-Database.mdb becomes mmddyyyy-prev04-Database.mdb 
mmddyyyy-prev02-Database.mdb becomes mmddyyyy-prev03-Database.mdb 
mmddyyyy-prev01-Database.mdb becomes mmddyyyy-prev02-Database.mdb
```

Comment: so, you save the result of the math to newname and then set newname to the basefilename and the calculated field. Simple